# How to get Physical Sector Size in .NET without PInvoke or Admin elevation on Windows 8

Tags: c#, .net, windows-8

I know in windows 8\server 2012 there is a new native API named FileFsSectorSizeInformation to get physical sector size from any file handle even over SMB2 without admain elevation.  I'm looking for the .NET equivalent.  Here is some more info on the native way.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh848035(v=vs.85).aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj216474.aspx

I'm using .NET 4.5

Comment: Why is this a concern for you? Knowing the sector size is necessary for unbuffered I/O and low-level file system operations, neither of which is supported by .NET without P/Invoke

Comment: In .NET 4\4.5 there is a new [FileStream.Flush(Boolean)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee474552.aspx).  I am doing some experiments with that and it would be helpful in my testing to be able to get the Physical Sector Size.  Also I may still PInvoke to get unbuffered IO with FileStream but I like to limit my PInvoke as much as possible.  Just because I use it for one thing does not mean I want to use it all over.  If there is a clean .NET way of doing it, I would rather use that.

Comment: I am also trying to optimize my use of [System.IO.Log](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms569883(v=vs.110).aspx) which is new in .NET 3.0 and it appears I can do that by knowing the underlying physical sector size.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, that's not wrapped by .NET.  It is not an api, it is a *driver control code*.  You'll need to pinvoke DeviceIoControl() to use it.  .NET in general avoids these low-level driver implementation details, too hard to keep them stable across Windows versions.

Do watch out here, what you contemplate doing doesn't make much sense in general.  Calling FileStream.Flush() would be necessary to ensure that logging data gets written before your program crashes so you can be sure you have an up-to-date log.  Passing *true* to the overload is extremely detrimental to perf, disk writes are very slow, it is only necessary if your program is in the habit of blue-screening the machine.  You should then also be very un-interested in the drive sector size.  Because the only way you can take advantage of that knowledge is to buffer log data.  Buffering is the last thing you want to do if you also use Flush().

Comment: The only reason I'm interested in Flush(Boolean) is in creating a durable queue that would survive a power outage and not corrupt a file.  I am extremely sparing with Flush and only call it when necessary.  Currently I'm using System.IO.Log but that really seems like overkill and the wrong solution for just a FIFO queue.  I'm basically going for something similar to [Tape](https://github.com/square/tape) in Java but that makes some assumptions about sector size.  I have many performance metrics so I can empirically know if I've gained anything over using System.IO.Log.